# Average for each hour of the year over several years with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, copernicus

How can I get the average value for each hour of the year for several variables from the era5 data set via Google Earth Engine?

This script extracts the hourly values for a set of coordinates. This works well but the output is way too large. Therefor I only want to calculate the average value for each hour of the year. How can I do this?

```
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xyz/coords');

function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  };
}

function zonalStats(ic, fc, params) {
  // Initialize internal params dictionary.
  var _params = {
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: null,
    crs: null,
    bands: null,
    bandsRename: null,
    imgProps: null,
    imgPropsRename: null,
    datetimeName: 'datetime',
    datetimeFormat: 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
  };

  // Replace initialized params with provided params.
  if (params) {
    for (var param in params) {
      _params[param] = params[param] || _params[param];
    }
  }

  // Set default parameters based on an image representative.
  var imgRep = ic.first();
  var nonSystemImgProps = ee.Feature(null)
    .copyProperties(imgRep).propertyNames();
  if (!_params.bands) _params.bands = imgRep.bandNames();
  if (!_params.bandsRename) _params.bandsRename = _params.bands;
  if (!_params.imgProps) _params.imgProps = nonSystemImgProps;
  if (!_params.imgPropsRename) _params.imgPropsRename = _params.imgProps;

  // Map the reduceRegions function over the image collection.
  var results = ic.map(function(img) {
    // Select bands (optionally rename), set a datetime & timestamp property.
    img = ee.Image(img.select(_params.bands, _params.bandsRename))
      .set(_params.datetimeName, img.date().format(_params.datetimeFormat))
      .set('timestamp', img.get('system:time_start'));

    // Define final image property dictionary to set in output features.
    var propsFrom = ee.List(_params.imgProps)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var propsTo = ee.List(_params.imgPropsRename)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var imgProps = img.toDictionary(propsFrom).rename(propsFrom, propsTo);

    // Subset points that intersect the given image.
    var fcSub = fc.filterBounds(img.geometry());

    // Reduce the image by regions.
    return img.reduceRegions({
      collection: fcSub,
      reducer: _params.reducer,
      scale: _params.scale,
      crs: _params.crs
    })
    // Add metadata to each feature.
    .map(function(f) {
      return f.set(imgProps);
    });
  }).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.notNull(_params.bandsRename));

  return results;
}

// Define parameters for the zonalStats function.
var params = {
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  bands: ['temperature_2m', 'surface_net_solar_radiation', 
          'u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m',
          'surface_pressure', 'total_precipitation',
          'surface_solar_radiation_downwards','surface_thermal_radiation_downwards']
};


var eraDat = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
  .filterDate('1981-01-01', '2021-01-01');

// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var ptsTopoStats = zonalStats(eraDat, pts.select('plot_id'), params);

var multiPropNoGeom = ptsTopoStats.select({
  propertySelectors: ['plot_id','timestamp',
          'temperature_2m', 'surface_net_solar_radiation', 
          'u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m',
          'surface_pressure', 'total_precipitation',
          'surface_solar_radiation_downwards','surface_thermal_radiation_downwards'],
  retainGeometry: false
});

var namelist = ['temperature_2m', 'surface_net_solar_radiation', 
          'u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m',
          'surface_pressure', 'total_precipitation',
          'surface_solar_radiation_downwards','surface_thermal_radiation_downwards'];

function exportResults(ivar){
    Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: multiPropNoGeom,
    folder: 'out_folder',
    selectors: ['plot_id','timestamp',ivar],
    description: ivar,
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });
}
namelist.map(exportResults)
```

I already tried to apply this.

```
var hours = ee.List.sequence(1, 24);

var byHour = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      hours.map(function (h) {
        return eraDat.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 366, 'day_of_year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(h, h, 'hour'))
                    .select(1).mean()
                    .set('hour', h);
}));
// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var ptsTopoStats = zonalStats(byHour, pts.select('plot_id'), params);
```

But it is not working and gives me this error.

```
Error in map(ID=0):
Image.date: Image '0' does not have a 'system:time_start' property.
```

So there seems something wrong with the zonalStats function now.
But I am new to the GEE and I cannot really solve the issue on my own. Does anyone have a clue what I can do to finally get the average for each hour of the year over all years?